# How do I change text color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

Okay, I'm trying to make a greasemonkey script for facebook, and I need to change the color of the home button text to black, I managed to do it for the button that has your name on it, but I cant figure out how to do it for the home button!
This is how I did the button with your name on it, which works great!

```
$('.headerTinymanName').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

This is the css it has for the home button, but I have no idea how to change the color!

```
.slimHeader #pageNav a{color:#d8dfea}
```

I'm very confused, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Technically, applying `each` to the selector is redundant because calling `css` on that selector will already loop through all the items from your original selector. You can simply replace it with `$('.headerTinymanName').css('color', 'black')`

Comment: Also, are you asking about how to find that CSS element in jQuery?

Comment: $('.headerTinymanName').css('color', 'black') doesn't work, All I want to do is make the home button text on facebook black, with a greasemonkey script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this GreaseMonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           FBoo
// @namespace      FBoo
// @description    FBoo
// @include        https://www.facebook.com/home.php
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('#navHome a').css('color', 'black');
```

If you want to give all the `a` tags in the header a black color at once you could go along these lines:

```
$('#headNav a').css('color', 'black');
```

Alternatively, you could do it without jQuery. A slightly hackish suggestion along those lines would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#navHome a')[0].style.color = 'black';
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you could assign another css class by using

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

Comment: Do you mean, document.getElementById("pageNav").slimHeader += " MyClass"; then use the other code I used with MyClass?

Comment: no no, className is the attribute :), create another class with the new color, e.g. NewColorClass and than write    document.getElementById("pageNav").className += "NewColorClass"

Comment: if you want to remove the previous class, than simply write = instead of +=, since this will add another class, it is also important to add a space within the quotes " NewColorClass" if you will use +=